# cannot write mode PA as PNG

Tags: python, pdf, pymupdf

```
pdf_file=fitz.open(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\example.pdf")
for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):
            page=pdf_file[page_index]
            print(page.get_pixmap())
```

```
OSError: cannot write mode PA as PNG
```

How i can get images from pdf file ?

I try to get images from pdf file

Comment: Please show your actual code, not just a small part of it. We can't tell what `pdf_file` is from this.

Comment: Can u check it now

Comment: You might want to consider using pypdf: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-images.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation for the `PyMuPDF` library you're using](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes-images.html#how-to-extract-images-pdf-documents) has an explicit section on extracting images from PDF documents, with [this example code](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities/blob/master/examples/extract-images/extract-from-pages.py) (which is a bit too long to include here, and under the GPL anyway).

It simplifies to something like

```
import fitz

doc = fitz.open(filename)
seen_xrefs = set()
for page_num in range(doc.page_count):
    for img in doc.get_page_images(page_num):
        xref = img[0]
        if xref in seen_xrefs:
            continue
        image = doc.extract_image(xref)
        imgfile = f"img{xref:05d}.{image['ext']}"
        with open(imgfile, "wb") as fout:
            fout.write(image["image"])
        seen_xrefs.add(xref)
        print(f"Page {page_num}: {imgfile} ({image['width']} x {image['height']}")
```

when not taking masks and color spaces into account.

Comment: It was not save images to local folder

Comment: @YAŞAREMREDOĞRU I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean with that.